# can we use form for every tr to the single table? and how?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to apply form for every tr  to a single table. 
That tr have 3 or 4 tds. But table in tr shouldnt use.  Is this possible?

This the example - http://jsfiddle.net/PBGXA/

Comment: You can try it and see if it is possible no?

Comment: There are no forms in your jsfiddle

Comment: I just noticed the `ajax` tag.  Is there more to this setup that you're not telling us about?

Comment: No, i am not working on ajax. i just added in tag because of if they know they will tell. incase if they had the experience working on tables.

Comment: @Pavanflash: If who knows what, they will tell what?  Do you want/need to use AJAX or not?  If you're not looking for an AJAX solution, you should remove the tag.

Comment: David: If it is possible in ajax also i am ready to go with that.

Comment: Post all of your code here, not on a separate site.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your form tags into whatever cell of the table. Nothing wrong with it

Comment: but when he has inputs in more tds? ;)

Comment: then he has inputs in more tds. I see no problem either

Comment: and form will be before <td> ?

Comment: whenever you put it. I see no point in these questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many forms as you want on a single HTML page, just keep in mind that each one will post only the values within itself.  Though I don't think it would be valid HTML to have the form tags break up the table's markup (like, have a `form` tag between the `table` and the `tr` tags).  You can consider:

1. Have a single form wrapping the entire table and differentiate the submitted values on the server-side.
2. Don't use a table for the layout and wrap style-aligned divs in the form tags.
3. If you're really keen on using tables and multiple forms, you may have to have a primary table with single-cell rows which contains the forms and then each form's cell contains an inner table with the columns.  It would be more valid HTML, but it would be messy.

I'd recommend option 1 or 2.

If all of the forms post to the same resource then I'd really suggest option 1.  You can still have multiple submit buttons and [differentiate which one was clicked in server-side code](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/handling-multiple-submits-in-a-single-form-with-php/5242116).

Comment: But he can use the HTML 5 attribute "form" attribute for the form controls. So he only need to define a single tag: `<form name="a" />`. http://jsfiddle.net/PBGXA/

Answer (score 0):

just put `<form>` before `<table>` and `</form>` after `</table>`. That's the easiest (and probably the only) way

```
<form method="post" action="">
   <table>
     ...
   </table>
</form>
```

or better one, do not use tables

Comment: Not that is what i want. I have different data for each tr. i need to apply form separately.

Comment: it isn't possible to put form before `<tr></tr>`. Use more tables or do not use tables

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: it's against standards. `<table><form><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></form></table>` ? No.

Comment: <table><form><td>data</td><td>data</td></form> <form><td>data</td><td>data</td></form> </table>   like this possible to write?

Comment: @Pavanflash: no it isn't. Missing <tr></tr> & this is AGAINST STANDARDS

Comment: @genesis: so whats your opinion for that solution